# function for Phone number to words in java for multiple digits

Tags: java, android

I want to make a function like 
if I enter 9898974123 it should convert into such output: Nine Eight Nine Eight Nine Seven Four One Two Three

Comment: Hint: `number.replaceAll("9", "Nine ")`

Comment: Calling a replaceAll is not efficient because the method iterate over the entire string for 10 time (0->9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call numToWords with your number. Otherwise if you already have a string just pass it and skip the String.valueOf(number) calling directly the split

```
private static final HashMap<String, String> mapping;
static
{
    mapping = new HashMap<>();
    mapping.put("0", "Zero");
    mapping.put("1", "One");
    mapping.put("2", "Two");
    mapping.put("3", "Three");
    mapping.put("4", "Four");
    mapping.put("5", "Five");
    mapping.put("6", "Six");
    mapping.put("7", "Seven");
    mapping.put("8", "Eight");
    mapping.put("9", "Nine");
}

private String numToWords(int number) {
    String[] num = String.valueOf(number).split("(?!^)");

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < num.length; idx++) {
        s.append(mapping.get(num[idx]) + " ");
    }

    return s.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a String array

```
String [] arr = {"zero", "one", "two" .....};
```

for each char, read and convert to an offset of `0`

```
for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); ++i) {
        char num = number.charAt(i);
        int index = num - '0'; 
        System.out.println(arr[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you...

```
    String hash[] = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"};

    String str = "9898974123";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        sb.append(hash[c - 48]).append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
```

Comment: i like the way you think

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {

  private static final Map<Character, String> values;

  static {
    values = new HashMap<Character, String>();
    values.put('1', "One");
    values.put('2', "Two");
    values.put('3', "Three");
    values.put('4', "Four");
    values.put('5', "Five");
    values.put('6', "Six");
    values.put('7', "Seven");
    values.put('8', "Eight");
    values.put('9', "Nine");
    values.put('0', "Zero");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String number = "9898974123";
    IntStream.range(0, number.length()).mapToObj(number::charAt).map(values::get)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

output :

```
Nine
Eight
Nine
Eight
Nine
Seven
Four
One
Two
Three
```

Answer (score -1):

If the number you enter is a String you could use something like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String number = "1234";

        for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); ++i) {
            char symbol = number.charAt(i);
            String nameOfSymbol = getName(symbol);
            System.out.println(nameOfSymbol);
        }
    }

    private static String getName(char symbol) {
        switch (symbol) {
            case '0':
                return "zero";
            case '1':
                return "one";
            ...
    }
```